# iOS social framework for facebook issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I recently was using social framework for posting on facebook and twitter both. Twitter works fine, even facebook works if the device dont have facebook app in it. But, if it in installed then it open some other window with no initial text.
Do anyone have any idea why is this happening and can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: What initial text? You have read Facebook Platform Policy?

Comment: Sorry I didnt read the policy. But, we have a parameter for setting the initial text. Framework itself provides it

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController
                                                      composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [composeController setInitialText:@"I’ve been using the app and think you might enjoy it."];
        
        [self presentViewController:composeController
                           animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Prefilling text is not allowed. That is why it doesn't work

Comment: It does work when facebook app is not installed.... So is that a bug or something?

Comment: Is there any workaround by which I can share static text?

Comment: please share your code or  please explain your answer clearly.

Comment: SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; [composeController setInitialText:@"I’ve been using the app and think you might enjoy it."]; [self presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];

This is what I am using to share static text "I’ve been using the app and think you might enjoy it." on facebook.

If facebook app is not installed in the device then the code opens a window with static text set. (This is expected behaviour)

Comment: But if facebook app is installed then it open the window shown in question with no initial text set

Comment: You are not allowed to specify the message part of a Facebook post/share for the user. It has to be typed in by the user him-/herself. It does not matter if the framework you are using makes it possible under certain circumstances - it is not allowed, so don't do it. Violating policy will only get your app banned by Facebook sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

you can share text, image, links by using SLComposeViewController, i hope it will work for u.

```
   let mySLComposerSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    mySLComposerSheet.setInitialText("Sharetext")       
    mySLComposerSheet.addURL(NSURL(string: "www.shareurl.com"))
    mySLComposerSheet.addImage(UIImage(named:"image"))
    mySLComposerSheet.completionHandler = {
    (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) in
        mySLComposerSheet.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            if result == SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done {
               print("success")
            } else {
                print("fail")
            }
        });
    }   
  self.presentViewController(mySLComposerSheet, animated: true) { () -> Void in

 }
```

swift3.0

```
let mySLComposerSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    mySLComposerSheet.setInitialText("Sharetext")
    mySLComposerSheet.add(URL(string: "www.shareurl.com"))

    mySLComposerSheet.add(UIImage(named: "image"))
    mySLComposerSheet.completionHandler = {
        (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) in
        mySLComposerSheet.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            if result == SLComposeViewControllerResult.done {
                print("success")
            } else {
                print("fail")
            }
        });
    }
    self.present(mySLComposerSheet, animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
```

Comment: I know how to share the text..... Problem occurs when the device has facebook app installed in it. In this case, another window opens (pic in the question) which has no initial text.
Expected behaviour is that the code should open the same social framework window, which open by default